# addClass not working within setTimeout function

Tags: jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CL4VD/)

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
   },500);
});
```

The active class should be added after 500 ms but it's not adding that is not changing it's background color.

Comment: Two words - `function scope`

Comment: For completeness, using queue() would be the jQuery'ish way to do it -> http://jsfiddle.net/CL4VD/4/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` doesn't refer to the clicked button inside the setTimeout() handler, you can use a simple closure variable to hold a reference to the clicked element and use it in the timeout handler

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.addClass('active');
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
   },this),500);
});
```

within setTimeout function 'this' refers to window object not to the button that you click on but using proxy the 'this' defines the button that you click on.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CL4VD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can save `$(this)` in a variable in order to access `$(this)` in your `setTimeout` function:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.addClass('active');
    },500);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CL4VD/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
 var that = $(this);
 setTimeout(function(){that.addClass('active');},500);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CL4VD/3/)**